# Flow of execution in TypeScript (Angular)

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to learn descriptors in Angular. I am trying this piece of code just to see how descriptors can manipulate the original methods. But I can see that the @squareLog funtion's "console.log()" statement is getting executed first and rest of the code executes in order. I am 100% noob in Typescript and Angular. Is the output correct? Is this what should have been expected from this code? If no,then did I messed up somewhere down the line?

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

function log(target, name, descriptor){
  //store the original function in a variable
  const original = descriptor.value;
  //do some manipulation with descriptor.value
  descriptor.value = function(){
    console.log("This function is with LOG as the descriptor");
  }
  //return the descriptor
  return descriptor;
}

function squareLog (target, name, descriptor){
  console.log("This function is with SQUARELOG as descriptor");
  const original = descriptor.value;
  descriptor.value = function(...args){
    console.log("Arguments ", args, "were passed in this function");
    const result = original.apply(this, args);
    console.log("The result of the function is ", result);
    return result;
  }
  return descriptor;
}

function classLog(className){
  console.log(className);
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})

@classLog
export class AppComponent {
  title: string = 'Demonstration of decriptors';

constructor(){
  this.aSimpleMethod();
  console.log("This statement was generated by constructor: ", this.returnSquare(5));
}
  @log
  aSimpleMethod(){
    console.log("Learning about descriptors");
  }

  @squareLog
  returnSquare(a){
    return a*a;
  }
}
```

Actual Output:-
[image]

Comment: interesting question, I was not even aware about this

Comment: please look on this, maybe helps you
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html

Comment: Hey thanks guys! But I understood what went wrong there. Since the statements inside the descriptot.value() did not got executed. I though that the functions(here i.e, log, squareLog) which are used as descriptor are executed, only when the function it wraps is invoked( as in this case invoked in the constructor). But it looks like that the code still executes sequential ;and only descriptor.value is executed, when the function(aSimpleMethod, returnSquare) on which descriptors are used is invoked. Function defined for the purpose of being used as descriptors still executes where it is defined.

Comment: please consider to upvote my answer, happy to know if I have helped you.

Answer (score 1):

```
function f() {
    console.log("f(): evaluated");
    return function (target, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
        console.log("f(): called");
    }
}

function g() {
    console.log("g(): evaluated");
    return function (target, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
        console.log("g(): called");
    }
}

class C {
    @f()
    @g()
    method() {}
}
```